# Why this code fall into an infinite loop?

Tags: llvm-ir

LLVM Version 5.0.0

I worte this code and build with clang/llvm.
But, I cannot understand why this code is converted to an infinite loop.

This code is my c++ code for build.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo()
{
  for (int j= 0; j < 23; j++)
    putchar('a');
}
int main()
{
  foo();
}
```

I used following command lines.

```
clang -O0 a.cpp // a.out not working
clang -O1 a.cpp
-O2 -O3 ... also
```

I can find an error in LLVM-IR too.

```
clang -S -O1 -emit-llvm a.cpp
clang -S -O1 -mllvm -disable-llvm-optzns -emit-llvm a.cpp 
   + opt -S -O1 a.ll
```

---

```
define i32 @_Z3foov() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  br label %for.cond

for.cond:                                         ; preds = %for.cond, %entry
  %call = tail call i32 @putchar(i32 97)
  br label %for.cond
}
```

But this code worked very well.

```
int main()
{
  for (int j= 0; j < 23; j++)
    putchar('a');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing return statements on your functions, `int foo()` and `int main()`. That is likely causing undefined behavior as specified in the ISO C++ standard section 6.6.3:

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no
>   value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning
>   function.

You should be seeing an error after `clang -O0 a.cpp`

```
a.cpp:7:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
```

Here's a version that should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int foo()
{
  for (int j= 0; j < 23; j++)
    putchar('a');
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  foo();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```